# TYPO3: tx_news import service error: Desired storage "" is not available

Tags: import, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I'm trying to activate the import service in the TYPO3 extension tx_news.

I suspect the error message: ***Desired storage "" is not in the list of available storages*** is due to the definition of the extension setting field `import module.resourceFolderImporter`, but no matter what i fill in there, I have this error ... this is as far as I get ... and that the value that I give in the variable is not shown in the error-message might be a hint ...

I tried it local on xampp (windows) and on the web-server, access rights should not be the issue

**ADDED:**
[news 7.0.5 import service](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/DeveloperManual/ExtendNews/ImportService/Index.html) I try to activate the first way "show importer" (I have news 6.3.0 installed) that activation demands also a folder where to save files and images.

Comment: Please provide all the information what and how you try to achieve exactly, including the essential code you're using. If you've special information related to documentation, please also provide the links.

Comment: @David I added some ... it should be standard behaviour ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error:

**UID of storage to use when importing files/images**

`import module.storageUidImporter (integer)`

this field asks for a storage, I was filling in a folder in the page-tree that I setup for the news import, instead it asked for a storage, as suggested right below the field, I used the default 1 for the fileadmin folder and the error resolved ...

real beginners error !